# ORA-01722 invalid number on different numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a condition in a query:

```
ABS ( FIB.QUANT1 ) = ( OI.KLINE * :intv1000 ) / 1000.000000
```

when I run the query with intv1000 = 1000000 - query runs ok.

when I run the query with intv1000 = 1000 I get ORA-01722 (not immediately, after about 5-6 seconds).

Any Idea why ?

QUANT1 - NUMBER(16,2)
KLINE  - NUMBER(38)

The condition is self generated from the application, So I can't really change it.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the issue is in this condition and not somewhere else? That is: what if you run the query without this condition?

Comment: Share your query, and the structure of the tables used in your query.

Comment: Well, Now when investigating more I think the problem is somewhere else - in to_number function somehow .. 
I still don't understand how
the condition is 
PRIV.CUST = to_number(:SILVERCUST$)
when I send the parameter as '8' I get the invalid number, 
but when I send it as 8 it works ok. 
very strange. 
The column datatype is NUMBER(38)

Comment: if you send '8', it has quotes in there, and it is not a number. These are bind variables not replacement variables. Sending '8' is NOT like to_number('8') but more like to_number('''8''')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ORA-01722 is an invalid number error.

You would get this error when a non-number -- typically a string -- has to be converted to a number.  For example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=730c4e134ee5f22e824dfc818e1d0a94).

This conversion can occur in many different ways although the three most common are:

- `to_number()`
- `cast()`
- implicit conversion

The expression you have highlighted may or may not have anything to do with where the error actually occurs.  What it is saying is that:

- When `:intv1000 = 1000000` then the row(s) with the problem data are filtered out.
- When `intv1000 = 1000` then the row(s) with the problem data are being processed.

Arrggh.  This is very hard to determine.  I would suggest starting by looking at the query and finding all explicit conversions to see if they are a problem.

If you find no back data, then you need to resort to looking at all comparisons (including joins), arithmetic expressions, and function calls to find the problem.

In general, I strongly recommend avoiding implicit conversion.  Use explicit conversion to avoid such problems!  Note:  I do make an exception for conversion to strings with string functions and operators.  These are usually pretty safe.